# How to drop partitions from hive views?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hive, hive-partitions, partitioned-view

I have a partitioned view and I am trying to drop an existing partition from the view definition using hive CLI. However, when I try to drop a partition, it throws me the following error:

```
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. null
```

Here is my create statement for view:

```
CREATE or replace VIEW test_view (logrecordtype, datacenter, ts_date, gen_date)
PARTITIONED ON (ts_date, gen_date)
AS SELECT logrecordtype, datacenter, ts_date, gen_date from test_table1 where ts_date <= '20200720'
union all
select logrecordtype, datacenter, ts_date, gen_date from test_table2 where ts_date != '20200720';
```

The underlying tables **test_table1, test_table2** are also partitioned by **(ts_date, gen_date)**.

Drop partition command:

```
ALTER VIEW test_view DROP IF EXISTS PARTITION (ts_date = '20200720', gen_date = '2020072201')
```

I am able to add partitions and issue show partition on my view but drop partition fails.

My show partition command shows:

```
show partitions test_view;
ts_date=20200720/gen_date=2020072201
```

Comment: try `ALTER VIEW test_view DROP IF EXISTS PARTITON(ts_date='20200720'),PARTITION(gen_date='2020072201')`

Comment: It didn't work.

Comment: can you share the output of `show create table test_view`?

Comment: `CREATE VIEW test_view AS SELECT logrecordtype AS logrecordtype, datacenter AS datacenter, ts_date AS ts_date, gen_date AS gen_date FROM (SELECT test_table1.logrecordtype, test_table1.datacenter, test_table1.ts_date, test_table1.gen_date from schema.test_table1 where test_table1.ts_date <= '20200720'
union all
select test_table2.logrecordtype, test_table2.datacenter, test_table2.ts_date, test_table2.gen_date from schema.test_table2 where test_table2.ts_date != '20200720') test_view` is a ddl I got even after creating a view ++

Comment: ++with `CREATE or replace VIEW test_view (logrecordtype, datacenter, ts_date, gen_date)
PARTITIONED ON (ts_date, gen_date) ...`. please share your view ddls after creation. `show parititons test_view` also not retrieving any output for me in hdp hive.